# Android: Color a bitmap

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I have a simple question. I have this bitmap
[image]

Is there a way with android sdk to color this T-shirt (and only the t-shirt not the whole rectangle) with a color (selected by the user)

Or do I have to make a bitmap of every color ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use e.g. ColorFilter to do what you want - or you use transparency ( make the area that should be colored transparent and draw a rect with the wanted color behind )

Comment: Yes, the transparency method works. I didn't try the ColorFilter, I don't know how to use it correctly

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i have made this image transparent 
you can also change some using Photoshop

USE this image or make Tshirt area of your image to transparent 
and change Background as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes, the transparency method works. I didn't try the ColorFilter, I don't know how to use it correctly